# What does "We're taking one for the team" mean?

Tags: meaning

I was looking at the [Send Your Enemies Glitter](http://shipyourenemiesglitter.com/) website, and there is a headline saying

> We're taking one for the team, this shit gets on everything.

What does "*We're taking one for the team*" mean exactly? Based on the context it sounds to me like "*we guarantee you*" or something like that, but I don't see the reasoning for using those particular words.

Comment: We're making a sacrifice so that the team as a whole will fare better.

Comment: [General reference](http://www.google.com/search?q=meaning+of+%22take+one+for+the+team%22&rls=en)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It comes from the world of sports.  When you play a team sport, sometimes you, the individual player, need to be tackled or get a penalty or be roughed up so the team as a whole can succeed.  The idiom means enduring something unpleasant for the greater good of the group.

In the case of this website, they mean they are enduring the unpleasantness of glitter on your behalf.  This particular usage is pretty cynical and snarky, but it isn't necessarily always used ironically.